# A decreasing function converging to 0 whose derivative diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

Can someone give me an example of a function that is decreasing monotonically,converges to $0$ as $x\to \infty$,but its derivative diverges as $x \to\infty$.I have an idea of how to make such a function but I cannot give its explicit form.I will construct a smooth functions with certain stair line sudden slants,and the slants each time will be steeper each time,It will roughly look like this[image]

Although sketch is very rough,I think I could convey my idea,constructing this way,I can guarantee that the derivative oscillates infinitely(unboundedly above),but function gradually approaches the value $0$.But I could not find any explicit form so that I could express my idea in a concrete form.I had seen a very construtive type function in the site mathcounterexamples.net from where I found this question too.But I was looking for a simple example.Is there any,can anyone help me get such a function or Can I guarantee that such a stairlike function can be constructed without explicitly constructing one?

Comment: You certainly need the limit $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f'(x)$ not to exist, rather then being infinite.

Comment: diverges means does not converge(definition).

Comment: Sorry, I tend to consider divergence as "going to plus or minus infinity". Then have a look at  my proposal, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A PATH**

If $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f'(x) = \pm \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \pm \infty$, by de l'Hopital's rule.

However, you can easily construct examples where the function monotonically tends to zero with *unbounded derivative*, when $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f'(x)$ *does not exist*.

Take, e.g.

$$t(x) = \begin{cases} 1-|x| & (|x|\leq 1) \\ 0 & (|x| > 1)\end{cases}$$

and define

$$g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} (2k-1) t\left((2k-1)k^2(x-2k+1)\right).$$

If you sketch it, you'll see repeated triangular shapes with increasing altitude and decreasing base, so that the area is "under control", what is the area of each triangle?

Then analyze:

$$f(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\int_0^x g(t) dt$$.

Comment: I was looking for a more simple example.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Simple is a bit subjective. But I understand this might look convoluted. :)

Comment: Still,I will accept your answer.It is an excellent example.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar if you find something alternative to functions defined by means of integrals, please do post it yourself. It might certainly be useful.

Comment: Yup I will,by the way did you check the mathcounterexamples.net.

Comment: can you help me to answer the unanswered questions in my account,posted this week.

Answer (score 1):

With some work you can show

$$\int_0^\infty t\left(\frac{2+\cos t}{3}\right)^{t^5}\,dt <\infty.$$

Letting the integrand equal $g(t)$ and $\int_0^\infty g =I,$ the function $f(x)=I-\int_0^x g(t)\,dt$ is then an example. Note $f'(2n\pi)\to -\infty$ and $f'(\pi/2 + 2n\pi)\to 0.$

Comment: I still do not know about Improper integral or even riemann integrals.